# I want to Disable postback of asp.net Button but will still be do the same job by jQuery?

Tags: .net, button

I'm trying to make a chat application.This is the source code of my aspx.cs page

```
public partial class home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private string chatitems
    {
        get
        {
            if(Application["un"]==null)
                Application["un"] = "";
            return Application["un"].ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            Application["un"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = chatitems;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chatitems = txt.Text + "<br />" + chatitems;
    }
}
```

I want the button to do the same thing but without any postback. Can this be achieved by using jQuery? If yes then can anyone tell me how?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using a `<asp:Button ID="Button1" ... />` server side control, just use an input html element of type submit

```
<input id="submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Then attach an event handler to your button for the on click event. This usually is done in a script at the bottom of your page before the closing tag

```
</body>
```

like the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // select the button element
    var button = document.getElementById('submitButton');
    // add an event listener for the on click event.
    button.AddEventListener("onClick", function(){
        var txt = document.getElementById('<%=txt.ClientId%>');
        // I suppose that you will define the chatitems somewhere above, because I don't //get its use, reading your code.
        chatitems += txt.val()+"<br/>";
    });
</script>
```